# How getopts is setting a bash variable

Tags: bash, getopts

I would like to re-implement my own getopts (in python if possible).

My problem is that I don't understand how this is possible:

```
# The call of the following script
./script -h

#!/bin/bash

getopts 'h' TEST # output nothing
echo $TEST # output h
env | grep # output nothing
```

We read all over the Internet that you can't set a variable in the parent process. But this is done here and without an export.

I want to understand how it works as I would like to do approximately the same in python. So my second question will be, is it possible to do the same in python?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Simple: `getopts` isn't running in a child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getopts` is a bash builtin. Since it operates within the shell process it is welcome to change shell variables at will.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, I've already seen this term "bash builtin" but without understanding it apparently. Is it possible to do the same in python? Do a python bash builtin ^^

Comment: No. Python is a separate process.

Comment: Adding/changing the bash builtins would require editing the bash source code and recompiling the modified version. The closest you can come without that would be to write a bash function to do what you want -- but it'd have to be written in bash, not Python.